# How to prove the regularity of one language given that another is regular?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Consider the following unary operation on languages: 
 **min(L) = {x ∈ L | no proper prefix of x is in L}** 
Prove that regular languages are closed under this operation; that is, prove that if language L is regular, then so is min(L).  
(hint: construct a DFA to accept Min(L) based on the DFA accepting L)

After searching online, I found out that I have to:

- Let M=⟨Q,Σ,δ,q0,A⟩ be a DFA that accepts L; Q is the set of states, Σ is the input alphabet, δ is the transition function, q0 is the initial state, and A is the set of acceptor states.
- To get a DFA that accepts min(L), add a new trap state q∗ and modify δ so that any input to an acceptor state sends M to q∗.

However, I have no idea to construct a DFA for language L where it does not explicitly state the Σ. Can anyone guide me? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not explicitly state the $\Sigma$"? Every language is over some alphabet, implicitly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what I was trying to say is that it does not state whether Σ = {a,b} or {0,1} etc. I'm still learning so forgive my mistakes.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the hint hinted that I should construct a DFA for it. Does it mean M=⟨Q,Σ,δ,q0,A⟩ will suffice or do I need to draw a diagram for it? Or what would you suggest me to do in this case? Thanks

Comment: You should think of $L$ as consisting of an alphabet $\Sigma$ and a subset of $\Sigma^*$, though usually we ignore the first part. Otherwise the definition of $\min(L)$ is ambiguous.

Comment: I would suggest asking your TA for personal guidance. Another option is talking to your peers.

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful for you to consider some examples. Find a DFA  for your favourite regular language $L$ and use it/modify it to build a DFA (or an NFA) for $min(L)$.

Comment: By the way, $\min(L) = L \setminus (L\cdot \Sigma^+)$.

Comment: @HansHüttel  Let M=(Q,Σ,δ,s,F);   
we define a new DFA M’=(Q,Σ,δ,s,F’ ),  
where F’={q ∈ F |  ¬∃y,z.δ(s,y)  ∈  F∧δ(s,yz)=q}      I found this after searching. Is this correct?

Comment: Try thinking for yourself instead of all that desperate googling. Draw your favourite automaton and then modifying it such that it will recognise $min(L)$.